# How I can set git fetch and rebase as the default operation for pull as a server config?

Tags: git

I have my own Git server and I would like to set Git Fetch and Rebase as the default operation of 'git pull'.

I like this configuration to remain on the server so whoever that clones the repository wouldn't need to do any configuration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `git pull --rebase` to do this. You can map it to an alias like this:

```
$ git config --global alias.rebasepull 'pull --rebase'
```

Now you can use `git rebasepull` instead of the previous command. You can't override GIT commands though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, thats not what I was looking for. I want to change the behavior of 'git pull' from 'Fetch & Merge' to 'Fetch & Rebase'. I also know how to set it up for my local repo, but not the remote repo.

Comment: You can't set something in the remote repo and use it in your repos. The remote only stores the repo, it doesn't modify it or modify it's clones.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it on the client with

```
git config branch.branchname.rebase true
```

or

```
git config branch.autosetuprebase always
```

But git doesn't have any way to push config from a server to a client; the best you can do is to put this in documentation somewhere, and/or establish a culture where people run a script upon cloning a repo that sets up config and hooks, and put those commands in that script.